# Dynamic class operations within a regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which excludes certain characters from a class based on the current content of capturing groups. The specific task that made me look for such a thing was to match lowercase letters in alphabetical order.

I searched through Rex's page (https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html) to see if there was any way to change the class' content, but was unable to find anything.

Take the following attempt as a brief example: `([a-z])[a-z--[\1]]`

Though it's not a correct regular expression, it demonstrates the concept. The idea is that it would match two letters that are not the same.

Note: the expression shown follows a Python-like syntax, and can also be written as:

`([a-z])[a-z&&[\1]]` or `([a-z])(?![\1])[a-z]`

But I am going to use the Python syntax.

In the examples above the nested brackets are optional(in certain engines), but for the ultimate goal they are necessary. The pattern I am trying to match the ordered letters with would be something like this:
`^(?:([a-z])([a-z--[a-(?(2)\2|\1)]])*+)?$`

The first character class matches a letter which is immediately captured by the group, meaning that the letter will be excluded from the group containing the conditional. the first time the second group tries to match, condition inside the conditional statement evaluates to false, since there has not been a second capture yet, so it "matches" the first group's content, which should result in the exclusion of the first letter from the class. In later steps the second group will be set, meaning that all the letters between 'a' and the most recently captured letter will be excluded.

I know, it seems complicated. Maybe refactoring the pattern will help, take a look at this one:

`^(?:([a-z])([(?(2)\2|\1)-z])*+)?$`

This example makes no use of set operations, but the idea is roughly the same. The first group matches a letter, then the class inside the second group matches anything between the captured letter and 'z', which is noted by the `[(?(2)\2|\1)-z]` part. The conditional is there to ensure that the lower boundary of the character interval is the most recently captured character.

This could also be written using subroutine calls, but I doubt it would solve the problem. The issue might be that the classes are precompiled (and so are subroutines), so they cannot change during the matching process.

Are you guys aware of a workaround or an engine that supports such operations? I am interested in the dynamic class operation itself rather than a different way to match alphabetically ordered letters.

Comment: can you  provide an input sample and what you expect as output

Comment: I'll give you an example with using the simpler regex (i.e. `^(?:([a-z])([(?(2)\2|\1)-z])*+)?$`)Take a simple string of letters in alphabetical order. Something like: "abcdefg".
The first group `([a-z])` matches the letter 'a'. The class within the second group at this point 'looks like' this: `[a-z]`. The second group has not been set yet, so the content of the first one is inserted, which is 'a', hence the [a-z]. Now the second group captures 'b'. In the next step, the second group is set, which results in changes inside the class within the group. It becomes `[b-z]`. And so on.